# How can I catch a truncation error in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, error-handling, insert

I'm attempting to insert data into a table. Say for example that this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE firstTable (first_name VARCHAR(5), last_name VARCHAR(10))
```

When I try to insert into this table, any data in the first_name field that exceeds 5 characters causes the following error.

**Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.**

Is there any way for me to catch this error in a stored procedure? I tried putting an `if @@ERROR <> 0` right after the insert statement, but the procedure never gets to the error check because the statement has been terminated!

Any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: What do you want to happen if the strings are too long?

Comment: I want to catch the error and pass on handling of it to a different procedure

Comment: In that case I think Martin's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`TRY ... CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

```
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO firstTable VALUES ('long string','foo')

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE()
/*The error will not be propagated to the client. You need
 to use RAISERROR if you want this to happen*/

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LEN` function to determine if the strings are too long before you do the insert. For example, if you wanted to just insert the truncated string you could do:

```
IF(LEN(@firstName) > 5) SET @firstName = LEFT(@firstName, 5)
IF(LEN(@lastName) > 10) SET @lastName = LEFT(@lastName, 10)
```

Comment: what would be nice is a little Function that would query the schema to see if a @parameter was too big for a column...

Comment: Yea, it would be easy to write a UDF `trimToLength` or something like that: `SET @firstName = trimToLength(@firstName, 5)`.